# Do children classes inherit parent's Destructors if not done manually?

Tags: c++, class, oop, inheritance, destructor

If given a parent class A that contains a defined Destructor, will B-it's child- execute it when creating a B object? even if I did not create manually nor inherit the A's Destructor in the B class?

I expect that it will since I saw it in a video tutorial of c++ but do not understand why? Because the Constructor was manually inherited!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler always implements a destructor for your class, if you haven't declared one. The compiler also generates code that calls base class destructors.

In other words, base class destructors are not inherited but get called from after your derived class destructor.

See [Destructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/destructor):

> **Destruction sequence**
>
> For both user-defined or implicitly-defined destructors, after the body of the destructor is executed, the compiler calls the destructors for all non-static non-variant members of the class, in reverse order of declaration, then it calls the destructors of all direct non-virtual base classes in reverse order of construction (which in turn call the destructors of their members and their base classes, etc), and then, if this object is of most-derived class, it calls the destructors of all virtual bases.
>
> Even when the destructor is called directly (e.g. obj.~Foo();), the return statement in ~Foo() does not return control to the caller immediately: it calls all those member and base destructors first.

Comment: I understand ! Would my compiler ever create a default Constructor if I already created one? Are default constructors ONLY created when I do not manually declare them?

Comment: See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor: _If no user-declared constructors of any kind are provided for a class type (struct, class, or union), the compiler will always declare a default constructor as an inline public member of its class._

Answer (score 0):

The child class inherits the data members and member function of parent class but private members remain inaccesible in child class.Only Public member function and data members are accecible in child class.In Inheritance constructor or destructor is not inherited by child class but in the child class constructor and destructor there is an explicit call to base class constructor and destructor.
whenever we create an object of child class ,first constructoe of base class will be invoked then constructor of derived class is called.while if the object of child class is destroyed the destructor of child class will be invoked first and then destructor of parent class will be called.